# How to prevent onClick before fully-load activity

Tags: android, android-activity, onclick

I've got 4 Activities with high-res drawables (for testing purposes) and Buttons on the same place on each activity. Click on a Button moves to a next Activity (Activity1 --click--> Activity2 --click--> Activity3 --click--> Activity4). Because of high-res pictures it takes about 0,5 second to load one Activity.

The problem. When user click 3 times on the button on Activity1 (before it even disappear) - Activity4 is opened.

It looks like clicks are cached somehow. How to prevent it (especially passing click to another Activity)?

Comment: Is this hdpi image coming from your res/ folder, or over the net..? I've never experienced a half second delay loading an image from device before. How big are we talking...?

Comment: It isn't really 0.5s it's less. But this is not important - release images will be much smaller. The clue is how to disable onClick before fully load an Activity. And why does it even happen ;).

Comment: it depends on how you are loading the image and where the pause is coming from. are you loading it over the network? from SD card? from /res? is the pause after you set the bitmap into the `ImageView`, or in parsing the encoded image into a `Bitmap`?

Comment: They are .pngs from res/drawables/ used as icons on Buttons background loaded from xml directly.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable button when click on it and enabled it in `onResume()` for each activity.

Comment: That's simple idea, thanks. I wonder if there is some explaination of the issue I get ;).

Comment: Are you use same layout for activities or same id name for all buttons?

Comment: No, every activity has its' own layout.

Comment: And buttons id is different in each layout?

Comment: Yes, they all are different.

Answer (score 0):

I can' tell if you're trying to stop `onClick()` from working until the image for the button in the curent activity is loaded or if you are concerned with the image in the other activites being loaded before letting the user switch to them (i.e. you don't want the user seeing a button in Activity 4 that has no background.). Here are my suggestions for both.

If its the first problem, why not just add a boolean flag to your activity? For example, let's say onClick your button triggers the method nextActivity. Create a variable buttonReady that is false at the start of your activity but set to true at the end of `onCreate()` - presumably when you're done processing that monster image. Then just add a conditional to the method you are triggering

```
public void nextActivity(View v){
    if(buttonReady){
        //start your next activity
    } else {
        Log.d("Button click", "Still loading. . .);
    }
}
```

This way you wont disable the ability to click on the button, just the effect. If the issue is that you don't want people using the button until the image is loaded, I'd follow a similar approach. Just use `findViewById` and set the button to be invisible until the bitmap is finished being processed, then make the button appear.

If your issue is that you want to delay `onClick` of the button until the images in the other activities are loaded, that's harder. My issue is that, a least upon the first launch, none of the images will be loaded - assuming you are processing the bitmaps within the activity that is using them. In this situation I have two possible suggestions:

(1) Set the buttons to be invisible until the image is processed as suggested above and bring it back when the image loads. For example to hide:

```
View button = findViewById(R.id.button);
button.setVisibility(View.GONE);(
```

(2) Create an image cache, load the images there durring the first activity and then access them from the other activities after the cache is populated. You can read more about [caching bitmaps here](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html).

To make this suggestion work you need to modify the method explained in the android docs a little. Rather than including the cache in one activity, use something like a [singelton pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) to initiate a cache that can be accessed accross the entire app. That way you only have to load the bimaps once.

Comment: Thanks. Actually there is no Activity visible, but the onClick is executed anyway. I want to prevent this behavior. It works similar for Button and ListView for ex. This solution is quite similar to AwadKabs' one.

Comment: Wait how is it executed with no activity ?

Comment: Activity1 (click, click) -> Activity2 blinks -> Activity3 loads.

Answer (score 0):

You could use AsyncTask with a progressdialog while loading the picture. after its done loading, you could set enable/clickable the next button. so its ensure that first the picture are loaded and after that you are able to go to the next activity.